# is HaltingFuck computable?

Tags: computability, programming-languages, turing-completeness

A while ago I defined the language [HaltingFuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Haltingfuck), but I've never been able to figure out its computational class. The language is defined as follows:

> HaltingFuck is a language very much like Brainfuck, with one key difference: instead of loops stopping when the value in the current cell is zero, they stop when the value in the current cell is the Gödel number of a HaltingFuck program that halts. The specific Gödel encoding is not specified since it doesn't affect any interesting properties of the language.

I argued on the page linked that HaltingFuck is a total language, because

> While it's very easy to write a HaltingFuck program that halts (for instance, the empty program), in order to write a HaltingFuck program that doesn't halt it is necessary to first write a HaltingFuck program that doesn't halt. This is because any HaltingFuck program that doesn't halt must contain at least one loop that starts with the current cell containing the Gödel number of a non-halting program. Since it is impossible to construct a non-halting program, every loop in a HaltingFuck program runs exactly zero times, and since every loop in a HaltingFuck program runs exactly zero times, it is impossible to construct a non-halting program.

But I'm not convinced that's true. Consider the encoding where 0 encodes `[]`. then the program `[]` halts if and only if the program `[]` halts, and as far as I can see we have no other information about whether it halts or not. I'm not sure how to interpret that, unless it means that the language is underspecified and there are two possible such HaltingFucks - a total one where `[]` halts and an uncomputable one where it doesn't.

Comment: How do you define a "program that does not galt"? Does it not halt for at least one input? Or does it never halt (i.e, doesn't halt for all inputs)?

Comment: Oraybe you have to encode the input as well, and then its defined as "a program that doesn't halt on the specified input"

Comment: oh, good point - yes, I guess I'm in the habit of thinking of input as part of the program in these sorts of discussions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it means that the language is underspecified and there are two possible such HaltingFucks - a total one where [] halts and an uncomputable one where it doesn't.

That's correct. The specification does not obviously define the semantics of the language in an unambiguous way. It's self-referential:

> they stop when the value in the current cell is the Gödel number of a HaltingFuck program that halts

To determine the semantics of a program containing a loop, you need to know whether some other program terminates. If that other program has a loop, you need to know whether yet another program terminates, and so on. Depending on the Gödel encodings, this can mean that there are multiple possible semantics, or none. Your example where the termination of `[]` depends on its own encoding is a simple example where there are either two HaltingFuck semantics corresponding to that encoding, or none at all, depending on the consistency of other programs.

What you've defined is not the semantics of a language, but a set of possible semantics for a language. That set depends on the precise choice of Gödel encoding. In other words, you've defined a (possibly empty) family of languages for each Gödel encoding. It's not obvious to me whether there are Gödel encodings for which that set is non-empty, or whether there are Gödel encodings for which that set has exactly one element.